# Unity3d generating an empty .sln file

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm following the [Hololens Developer 100](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_100) course from Microsoft. All goes well until I get to building. I follow the instructions exactly here and click build. It asks me to select a folder and I create a folder called "App" (per the instructions) and select that folder. When I finally hit build Unity seems like it's working fine but then two things go wrong:

1) The .sln file that's generated is not in the App folder, but in the parent project folder. The App folder is empty

2) When I open the .sln file, it's empty. The tutorial asks me to edit Package.appxmanifes, but I can't because it doesn't seem to have built.

Is there a configuration somewhere that's not correct? Perhaps Unity and VS aren't talking to eachother correctly? More Importantly, how do I fix it?

Comment: That .sln file is for the .cs scripts inside your Unity project, not for your deployment to the hololens. When it works sucessfully you will have two .sln files, one in the project root and one in the App folder. Double check that steps 6 through 9 of that section all complete sucessfully. And also check that you did not skip step 2 *"Click Add Open Scenes to add the scene"*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, for me it was that I didnt have the Windows 10 SDK installed as part of Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3, in the instructions there is a bit that says:

"If you choose a custom install, ensure that Tools (1.4) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586) is enabled under Universal Windows App Development Tools node. All editions of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 are supported, including Community."

Answer (score 0):

If your hololens build completes successfully a file explorer window will pop open at the project level.  If it fails you should find errors in the console tab of Unity.

The SLN file that is at the project level is a solution file that you can open in visual studio to edit unity code and attach to the unity editor to do real time debugging while running your solution in the editor.  In fact if you click on a "CS" file in the project tab of Unity this is the solution that opens in visual studio.

The SLN file you are looking for is in the App folder.  Once you open the SLN in visual studio set the configuration to Release and x86, and you should be able to target your build at either a "Remote Device" which is the hololens, or the hololens emulator if you have that installed.

Answer (score 0):

To regenerate your .sln and related files:

1. `Edit` -> `Preferences`
2. `External Tools`
3. Under `External Script Editor` select `Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx` (pick your version)
4. Press `Regenerate project files`